# How to install MySQL on OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: mysql, osx-mountain-lion

I tried downloading the MySQL community server from the MySQL website, however, when I try to open the installer, I get a popup saying "You may only run executables from the Mac App Store". What kind of tyranny is this!?

So I go to store.apple.com and type in "MySQL" into the search bar but it brings up no results. How am I supposed to install MySQL on my laptop??

Comment: Doesn't seem the same at first, but it's only because you got the dialog. [Quarantined apps / drives](http://rsbox2.heliohost.org/wordpress/?cat=15), [Mountain Lion: Hands on with Gatekeeper](http://www.macworld.com/article/1165408/mountain_lion_hands_on_with_gatekeeper.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely doing development, I would suggest using a LAMP stack.

MAMP is a program that gives you a development MySQL, php, apache stack on Mac

http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html

My preferred method is actually to use a linux VM. Take a look at Vagrant and Virtualbox

http://www.vagrantup.com

---

If you really want to just run MySQL Server on your mac (which I would discourage), you will need to allow unauthorized apps.

Choose "Anywhere"

[image]

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5290?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

---

If you just need the client and not the full mysql server, then simply allowing installed programs from anywhere should suffice. Though you may find the following programs very useful.

[sequel pro](http://www.sequelpro.com)
 [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)
 [mysqladmin](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Comment: I really only need the MySQL client, I wouldn't be running the server. Would you discourage using the client? In any case, if there's no easy way to install the client, I'll probably just end up using a remote linux box.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you just needed the client. You should be able to use the suggestion to "allow from anywhere". I've updated my answer with some alternatives you might find helpful.